# Winforms Control Layout at Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been working on developing a custom control which will be used in our CRM frontend. The control itself is nothing special, it simply wraps two labels, text edits, and a button into a single control. (The control is only acting as a wrapper, a bit long winded, but unfortunately our only option due to various restrictions)

I though it would be nice to give the control a Font and ForeColor property, that would change the Font and Color of the labels. Changing the font size means that the relative position of the text boxes be changed to keep everything in line. No problem.

I encapsulated the layout logic in an UpdateLayout method, which is called on the set accessor of the Font property and everything works beautifully at design time, however, at runtime, the Font of the labels is correct, but the layout of the text boxes and button are still in the default positions, hence, the labels overlap.

What am I missing in for updating the position of controls at the init stage in runtime? I've tried calling the UpdateLayout() method from both Initialize and the constructor of the control, alas to no avail.

Am i missing something obvious here?

EDIT:

As requested, I whipped up a quick test. My test control looks like so (Not including Designer code):

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    private Font _font;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return this._font ?? SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
        }
        set
        {
            this._font = value;
            this.DoLayout();
        }
    }

    private void DoLayout()
    {
        this.label1.Font = this._font;
        this.Size = new Size(label1.Width + textBox1.Width + 10,
            label1.Height >= textBox1.Height ? label1.Height : textBox1.Height);
        this.textBox1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 5 + label1.Width, 1);
        this.Update();
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLayout(e);
        DoLayout();
    }
}
```

That works great at design time, but runtime, less so...

EDIT2:

So the above code doesn't entirely reflect the problem accurately, however, I have tried Jogy's suggestion of overriding the OnLayout method, and lo and behold, it works!

I'm relatively new to Custom Controls, so a rookie mistake on my part. This will definitely be committed to the long term memory.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the OnLayout method and call UpdateLayout there?

Comment: I normally try to resolve positioning and size of controls within User or custom controls by applying a) the Dock property on the controls or by b) using Anchors. But as Patrick suggest some code on how you set-up / initialize the controls and how you do perform the Layout updating would be handy.

Comment: See the above edits. @Jogy Do you want to put your suggestion as an answer and I will mark correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `OnLayout()` method and call your `UpdateLayout()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for supplying the code, I would provide the properties by reusing already available controls.

```
public override Font Font
{
    get { return this.label1.Font; }
    set 
    { 
        this.label1.Font = value; 
        // Additional code to update related controls.
    }
}
```

Also be aware that the declaration of

```
private Font _font;
```

Delivers a non-initialized variable, and by using it in the "Do_Layout" might use a null value. Maybe change it to the following when using your code.

```
this.label1.Font = this.Font;
```

Comment: I know I've marked this question as answered, but just a quick note. Will the null not be negated by coalescing _font in the Font Get accessor? - Nevermind, I didn't use the public property in the example above. *Doh*